# How do you write a recursive stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database

I simply want a stored procedure that calculates a unique id (that is separate from the identity column) and inserts it.  If it fails it just calls itself to regenerate said id.  I have been looking for an example, but cant find one, and am not sure how I should get the SP to call itself, and set the appropriate output parameter.  I would also appreciate someone pointing out how to test this SP also.

**Edit**

What I have now come up with is the following (Note I already have an identity column, I need a secondary id column.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DataInstance_Insert] 
    @DataContainerId int out,
    @ModelEntityId int,
    @ParentDataContainerId int, 
    @DataInstanceId int out
AS
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WHILE (@DataContainerId is null) 
        EXEC DataContainer_Insert @ModelEntityId, @ParentDataContainerId, @DataContainerId output   

    INSERT INTO DataInstance (DataContainerId, ModelEntityId)
    VALUES (@DataContainerId, @ModelEntityId)   

    SELECT @DataInstanceId = scope_identity()                       
END    

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DataContainer_Insert]
        @ModelEntityId int,
        @ParentDataContainerId int,
        @DataContainerId int out
    AS
    BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @ReferenceId int

        SELECT @ReferenceId = isnull(Max(ReferenceId)+1,1) from DataContainer Where ModelEntityId=@ModelEntityId

        INSERT INTO DataContainer (ReferenceId, ModelEntityId, ParentDataContainerId)
        VALUES (@ReferenceId, @ModelEntityId, @ParentDataContainerId)

        SELECT @DataContainerId = scope_identity()
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH
    END
```

Comment: This has a pretty epic fail scenario. Typically if something doesn't work, the solution is not to try the *exact same thing* again and expect a different result.

Comment: @Rex M: Tell that to my manager.

Comment: Any recursive function can be written to be iterative using a simulated stack.

Comment: lol, I posted a question about how to handle concurrency when inserting a calculated user key (that is calculated NOT an identity), I was advised to resubmit on failure, but I have not found any examples on how to do this.  Perhaps, I should just try and resubmit once, as having a concurrency error would be rare, and then having two in a row infantisably small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better yet, why not make UserID an identity column instead of trying to re-implement an identity column manually?

BTW: I think you meant

```
VALUES (@DataContainerId + 1 , SomeData)
```

Comment: It is already an identity.....notice this line  SELECT @DataContainerId = scope_identity()

Comment: In that case, why are you even bothering to calculate the next available ID? SQL will do that for you. Just exclude the UserID column from the insert statement.

Comment: I am not.....I made the comment...but I didn't post this question.. :-) see my answer also

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I was assuming that the PK Was another column because @DataContainerId is never used for anything.

Comment: Hmm, I have simplified this down a bit far, but basically what I am trying to achieve is have a User key that is a different algorithm from the identity column.  Sorry that was not clear in my post (as I removed the original algorithm.

Comment: This post is a mess, but you left some funny comments, so am going to make you the winner

Comment: I see now. Normally when you find the need to have a second auto-incrementing column in the same table you've got some normalization problems. Consider adding a second table and making that column an identity, then make the column in your new table a foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

1. In CATCH blocks you **must** check the [`XACT_STATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx) value. You may be in a doomed transaction (-1) and in that case you are forced to rollback. Or your transaction may had *already* had rolled back and you should not continue to work under the assumption of an existing transaction. For a template procedure that handles T-SQL exceptions, try/catch blcoks and transactions correctly, see [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/)
2. Never, under any languages, do recursive calls in exception blocks. You don't check *why* you hit an exception, therefore you don't know if is OK to try again. What if the exception is 652, read-only filegroup? Or your database is at max size? You'll re-curse until you'll hit stackoverflow...
3. Code that reads a value, makes a decision based on that value, then writes something is **always** going to fail under concurrency unless properly protected. You need to wrap the SELECT and INSERT in a transaction and your SELECT must be under SERIALISABLE isolation level.

And finally, ignoring the blatantly wrong code in your post, here is how you call a stored procedure passing in OUTPUT arguments:

```
exec DataContainer_Insert  @SomeData, @DataContainerId OUTPUT;
```

Comment: That whole thing cannot ever run even once, did you notice this line   SELECT @DataContainerId = scope_identity()

Comment: @SQLMenace: The whole code is like a interview puzzle 'how many mistakes can you find in these 3 lines?'

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the:

```
 NewId()
```

T SQL function? (assuming sql server 2005/2008)

Comment: -1 because NEWID() is a moniker for UuidCreate, which is **not** a function to allocate new SQL identity values...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I've always been able to use the 'NewId' to generate a Guid and insert this without issue?

Comment: Also not sure what Remus meant.
Instead of NewId() I normally use NewSequentialId(), which is a bit better for indexing.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx

Answer (score 0):

that sp will never ever do a successful insert, you have an identity property on the DataContainer  table but you are inserting the ID, in that case you will need to set identity_insert on but then scope_identity() won't work

A PK violation also might not be trapped so you might also need to check for XACT_STATE()

why are you messing around with max, use scope_identity() and be done with it

Comment: Not only that, what is the point of recursing with @DataContainerId passed in when that parameter is never even used?